Sharing database access object across flutter/dart objects
I'm building my first flutter/dart app. I need to use local database - I chose ObjectBox but I think it doesn't really matter in context of my question.
For the last 2h I'm trying to find out what is the right/best way to share the DB connection object across flutter/dart objects (be it widgets, providers, riverpod providers etc).
I instantiate the connection to the ObjectBox db in the main method of my application which according to ObjectBox is the right way to do it.
How can I then share the DB object with the flutter/dart objects? With widgets I guess I can pass that via the constructor but that seems to me like awfully dirty solution? I looked up ObjectBox and SQLite examples but did not find an answer.

You want some sort of state management solution. Its probably worth reading through this section of the flutter documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt
